# Uploading image using Codeigniter (API)

Tags: php, api, codeigniter

I'm trying to implement a simple image upload function in my API using codeigniter. So far this is my code :

```
function addpicture_post()
{
      $config['upload_path'] = './upload/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '10000';
$config['max_width']  = '1024';
$config['max_height']  = '768';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload() )
    {
    print_r($this->upload->display_errors('', ''));
    print_r($this->upload->data());
    $info = 'not working';
    $this->response($info);
    }
}
}
```

When I'm using apigee (https://apigee.com/console/others) to try it, if I do not set any parameter, I have the following message :

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Status:
200
Date:
Thu, 12 Dec 2013 15:30:16 GMT
Content-Length:
367
Keep-Alive:
timeout=15, max=100
Content-Type:
application/json
X-Powered-By:
PHP/5.3.5-1ubuntu7.11
Server:
Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu)

You did not select a file to upload.

So far so good. But when I'm trying to upload an image file (with the file attachement parameter in apogee, which I named "userfile"), I have the following response :

**Invalid test url**

I'm fairly struggling with that for a few hours now, I've tried to look at code igniter's documentation but unfortunately it has nothing to do with APIs , and I can't figure out how to upload files without using a form.

I'm not quite sure if the problem is coming from the service I'm using to test it, apigee, or if the problem is coming from the code. At the end, my goal is to implement this function in an iphone app I'm coding, but I'd like to be able to test the function before trying to include it in my app.

Anyone could give me informations about file upload within an API ? And how to test it properly ? Thank you.

Comment: provide ur code of `view`

Comment: Unless you are doing something funky in your view I am pretty sure that your upload path does not need to have a **.** so it should be _/upload_ not _./upload_

Comment: I've changed the ./upload/ to /upload/, still not working. I don't actually have any view, as I'm only using Apigee to try it before implementing it in an iOS app.

Answer (score 1):

Try This, it works!

*input file name = 'image'

```
function upload_image(){
 $img = array(); // return variable
 $this->load->helper(array('file','directory'));
 if (!empty($collection)) {
    $path="./uploads/";
    if( !is_dir($path) ) {
        mkdir($path);
    }
    $config['upload_path'] = $path; /* NB! create this dir! */
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|bmp|jpeg';
    $config['file_name'] = 'image001';
    $config['overwrite']=TRUE;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);


    $configThumb = array();
    $configThumb['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $configThumb['source_image'] = '';
    $configThumb['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
    $configThumb['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;

      /* Load the image library */
    $this->load->library('image_lib');

      /* We have 5 files to upload
       * If you want more - change the 6 below as needed
       */
        /* Handle the file upload */
    if (isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
        $upload = $this->upload->do_upload('image');

        /* File failed to upload - continue */
        if($upload === FALSE){
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $data['message']=$error['error'];
            continue;   
        } 
        /* Get the data about the file */
        $data = $this->upload->data();
        $img['image']='/'.$data['file_name'];

    }

 }
        return $img;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it might help you, I did this using codeigniter frame work, here is the controller

```
function do_upload()
{
$config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size']             = 8000;
$config['max_width']            = 1024;
$config['max_height']           = 768;

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
{
$error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
$this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
}
else
{
$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
$this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
}
}
```

here is a view file

```
<?php echo $error;?>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>
<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
<input type="submit" value="upload" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple in codeigniter you can use this method also , take data from post
**method=multiform/form-data**

**And use this function for uploading the file by changing its name using md5 and store it in db**

```
$md5 = md5(date('d-m-Y H:i:s'));    //md5 the constant here i have choosen date()
  if(!empty($_FILES['profile_pik']['name']))  //check whether file is there or not
  {
   
  $moveprofilepik='assets/uploads/profile_pik/' . $md5.str_replace(' ', '', $_FILES['d_profile_pik']['name']);   //append the location where you want to move and also concat the name using md5 value
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['d_profile_pik']['tmp_name'], $move1);  //finally use inbuilt function move_uploaded_file and pass values 
 }
```